# Does iterating through a string slice create a new object?

Tags: python, string, memory-management

Let's say I have a `str` of length 5: `Hello`. If I wanted to iterate through every character from index `1` on, I'd do it like this:

```
s = 'Hello'
for c in s[1:]:
    # do something
```

Does looping like this create a new `str` object of length 4? I can see it being very memory inefficient with bigger strings...

Comment: It does, and it is. If this is a concern, I think [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) might be of use

Comment: Oh yeah, it's the exact same question. I guess I didn't know how to properly word it.

Comment: @shooqie No worries, appreciated for marking it as a duplicate yourself and having a thoughtful question. Just an FYI, Google can often be a better resource than the Stack Overflow search bar for finding questions on Stack Overflow, as strange as that may sound.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Also, doing `s[:]` will create a new string identical to the previous.

This works the same with lists too.